# Restore GRUB2 after Clonezilla

Tags: grub2, clonezilla

After restore from clonezilla backup, grub2 is broken.
I see "GNU GRUB minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.."..

I have one HDD, with two partition (/boot , and /)

[image]

default settings

[image]

How do I restore the bootloader ?

I did it! Right commands below

```
set root=(hd0,msdos1)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/grub
linux /vmlinuz-3..... **root=/dev/sda2**
initrd /initramfs-3....
boot
```

**bold** is very important!

Answer (score 1):

First, you enter commands on the GRUB prompt to boot the system:

```
root (hd0,msdos1)
linux /vmlinuz-3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/sda2 <other options>
initrd /initramfs-3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64.img
```

where "other options" may not be necessary, but if you know you need them, add them there.

This should boot your system somewhat normally. Once you've booted, log in as root, and regenerate the grub configuration:

```
update-grub
```

After that, reboot once more, so that any options which you didn't pass but which your system has configured in grub *are* passed on this time.

Comment: wrong commands.. See screenshot please - https://hsto.org/files/c5a/ded/ab0/c5adedab067c42a2b0cfa94ce0957e3f.png

Comment: i did it. Answer in bottom of my post

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me after partitioning my NVME drive with GParted (and after restoring a Clonezilla backup):

```
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-74-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p2
initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-74-generic
boot
```